# update app gradle API to target level 26 fails nes app

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an old classic game ice climber it was working perfect but unfortunately, google update terms to make all apps **`targetSdkVersion`** at least 26.

but I get an error in the **logCat** which is:

```
09-09 15:21:22.934 396-396/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/KII-L21/HWKII-Q:6.0.1/HUAWEIKII-L21/C185B321:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 9249, tid: 9249, name: XX.XXX:emulator  >>> XX.XXX.XXX:emulator <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
09-09 15:21:22.954 396-396/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 ac21b450  r2 abb85d00  r3 f355800c
        r4 ab2ac2f0  r5 ffa398b4  r6 ac21b450  r7 ffa398b0
        r8 abb85d00  r9 ffffffff  sl ffa398c0  fp ab2abce0
        ip 00000000  sp ffa39868  lr f3553eef  pc f3553e3e  cpsr 000f0030
09-09 15:21:22.974 396-396/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 00001e3e  /data/app/XXX.XXX.XXX-1/lib/arm/libemu.so
        #01 pc 000ead49  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
        #02 pc 000e6651  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
        #03 pc 003eb9cf  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+170)
        #04 pc 007fb9fc  [stack]
```

my old Gradle code is which runs app successfully is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 9
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

my new Gradke update to support the new terms (targetting API 26):

the reason why I added `'com.android.application'` because I was using some methods deprecated in the new version of Android.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

}
```

some additional info maybe help:

> my app is a classic game that runs nesoid file (game)
>
> in my `jniLibs` folder I've two armeabi folders `armeabi` and
>   `armeabi-v7a`

I know you may need more details but I don't know what needed to provide more for help.

Comment: logcat that you have posted doesn't seem to be any kind of error?

Comment: that is what shown when runs the app after app crashed

Comment: Well, the stacktrace points to a location in your library (libemu.so). Use `addr2line` or some other tool to find out which line of code the corresponds to.

Comment: can you explain more details please?

Comment: `arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -Cfe libemu.so 00001e3e`  (where `libemu.so` is the unstripped version of the library)

Comment: so what do you suggest to do to get the right version for this file and from where can I get it?

Comment: any help, please?